# crosspaltformui problem with MTS Mblaze

Tags: installation, 9.10

I have tried to install MTS Mblaze in my Karmic Koala. But it failed. When I am trying to use synaptic manger it says that software index is broken. So I am unable to do any updates.

I have already tried `dpkg` with `pure` and `remove`.

Also tried:

```
$ sudo apt-get -f
```

It always say that some package is partially installed (crossplatformui)

Is there any way to remove this manually ?

Answer (score 2):

Support for Karmic Koala has ended - and the repositories have been removed.

You will not be able to update using "apt-get install" anymore.

You will either need to upgrade to 10.04 via a `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` - or take the opportunity to do a nice clean install of the latest ubuntu - 11.04.

The only other alternative I can think of is to compile from source.

If you are using Karmic due to hardware issues such as lack of RAM - consider an install of Lubuntu or Xubuntu.

Comment: I think 10.04 is the LTS version should I prefer that ?.I have 1GB RAM.And I need the eclipse j2ee edition with google gwt plugin..etc.

Comment: You'll just need to remember that the 10.04 version of eclipse etc is slightly older that for 11.04/11.10.  If you are happy with that - 10.04 is supported until 2013.

Comment: thanks - if you are happy with the answer - please hit the tick button to close the question.